# Search by street name in a google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Is it possible to have a search ability - say in an action bar - that can search for street names in a google map fragment? I'm developing an app right now nd that would be very useful. If the app could then navigate to that location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can with the help of the Geocoder class. AFAIK the built-in android Geocoder relies on ESRI's geocoding web services.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    // Find a maximum of 3 locations with the name Kyoto
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Kyoto", 3);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (addresses != null) {
    for (Address loc : addresses) {
        MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()))
                .title(loc.getAddressLine(0));
        mMap.addMarker(opts);
    }
}
```

*Notes:*

- Geocoding process is synchronous and can take a while. You're suggested to wrap it in an AsyncTask.
- More information can be found on the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) (as usual).
- Alternatively you can use Google's Geocoding API, which however has [limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits).

**Edit:**

Based on [esri's arcgis developer website](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/geocoding-and-place-search.htm) the Geocoder relies on the ESRI's web services. I was surprised by this also, but it kind of makes sense since Google's Geolocation API has limitations, while there are no (not that I know of) limitations on the Android's `Geocoder` location functions.

Comment: What makes you think that the Location.Geocoder uses the ESRI services? No offense, I'm just asking because I tried to track down the source code of the Geocoder with no result. And it would be more obvious that Google uses a wrapper of their own webservice.

Comment: @SteveBenett I've made an edit to my answer providing the source.

Comment: thank you @user3249477 - but how does one implement this so it is searchable from the fragment? Isn't this going to just get the location name kyoto?